# Automapper issue, seems to ignore mapping of property

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I'm using Automapper version 6.2.2 and I'm having issues with mapping between two classes. Automapper is used in the project for all "mapping purposes" and works well for all cases except this one.

```
public class WeeklyVolume    
{    
    public DateTime Week    
}    

public class WeeklyVolumeViewModel    
{    
    public DateTime Date    
    public string Week    
}`
```

The mapping between the classes looks like:

```
CreateMap<WeeklyVolumeViewModel, WeeklyVolume>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Week, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date))

CreateMap<WeeklyVolume, WeeklyVolumeViewModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Week, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Week));
```

When this mapping is used

```
Mapper.Map<IList<WeeklyVolumeViewModel>, IList<WeeklyVolume>>(weeklyVolumes));
```

an exception is thrown:

Message: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : Error mapping types.

Mapping types:

- System.FormatException : v. 44 (0) is not a valid value for DateTime.
- System.FormatException : The string was not recognized as a valid
- DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

In the mapping, the string property Week from WeeklyVolumeviewModel is ignored. Though its value "v. 44 (0)" (formatted string with week number) still seems to be trying to get mapped to the WeeklyVolume Week property, which is what I'm guessing causes the error. All the other mappings between classes work great, but here it does not seem to function properly, or am I missing something?

All the mappings are set through using

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.Addprofile(new DummyMapperclass());
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would change is

```
public class WeeklyVolume    
{    
    public DateTime Week {get; set;}
}    

public class WeeklyVolumeViewModel    
{    
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string Week   {get; set;}
}
```

then, let's see on the field names: you have two fields with the same name, but with the different type. This may confuse Automapper. He will try to convert the fields.

You can try to change 'Week' on WeeklyVolume to 'Date' and remove all mappings 'Date' to 'Date' -> Automapper will do all things automatically.

OR
You can try to change field name Week (one of these) to say, Week2.

Let me know the results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I have experimented with renaming one of the "Week properties", then Automapper handles it and it works fine. Though I felt that this was not really solving the issue, just hiding the symptoms. Shouldn't Automapper handle the different data types of the properties with the ignore mapping I've created? If it cannot handle that I'll have to rename it, but I'd prefer to see if there is a way to map between different data types.

Comment: FWIW, I ran into this same issue. Automapper appears to ignore your custom mapping settings if the name matches on the src and destination, it will use that value instead, and not call your mapping.  I'm still looking for a solution, if you ever found one.

Comment: Seconds after I typed the above comment, I figured out that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454059/map-fields-with-same-name-to-different-fileds-in-automapper was my answer.