# Map fields with same name to different fileds in automapper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I have a model which I am trying to map from Match class in .net core 2.0.
Both the classes have a Name property.

I need to map **Match.Value => ViewCompany.Name**

But it always puts **Match.Name into ViewCompany.Name**

Here is my **AutomapperProfile**:

```
CreateMap<Match, ViewCompany>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value));
```

.ForMember(dest => **dest.Name**, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => **src.Value**))

**ViewCompany**:

```
public class ViewCompany
{
    public ViewCompany()
    {

    }

    public ViewCompany(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The above mapping doesn't work.

But if I change property name in the model to something else like "Value" or "tempName" and update the automapper profile, it works fine.

So, is it not possible to map properties with same names to different properties in Automapper?

Comment: Works for me, try upgrading.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I have the latest 6.0.0 version of Automapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: Most likely your configuration is ignored because you're not setting it up properly. Check [the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Configuration seems fine because I changed property "Name" to "CompanyName" and updated configuration .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value))  And it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens here is that `Name` is mapped through [the constructor](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html). A simple way to avoid that is to tell AM what constructor to use:

```
 CreateMap<Match, ViewCompany>().ConstructUsing(source=>new ViewCompany());
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was just trying the same in a new dummy project without that constructor and it worked.

Comment: Actually, I don't need that constructor anymore. So, I removed that and it's working as expected now. Thanks a lot @Lucian

Comment: The parameter in the lambda expression should be `dest` for not creating confusion:
`ConstructUsing(dest => new ViewCompany());`

Comment: Actually no :) You receive the source and you _return_ the destination.